# Output transactions that exceed certain amount within 3 days

Tags: c#, sql-server

In a month, seperate by AccountNo, all transaction that exceeds 10,000 amount within 3 days must be outputted.

This is a sample table:

```
AccountNo-----Date------------Amount
1-------------5/1/17----------8000
1-------------5/3/17----------1000
1-------------5/4/17----------1000
1-------------5/6/17----------1000
2-------------5/7/17----------3000
2-------------5/10/17---------2000
2-------------5/13/17---------2000
2-------------5/13/17---------3000
3-------------5/14/17---------3000
3-------------5/15/17---------3000
3-------------5/16/17---------9000
4-------------5/17/17---------1000
5-------------5/18/17---------1000
5-------------5/19/17---------1000
5-------------5/20/17---------1000
```

The result must be:

```
AccountNo-----Date------------Amount
1-------------5/1/17----------8000
1-------------5/3/17----------1000
1-------------5/4/17----------1000
2-------------5/7/17----------3000
2-------------5/10/17---------2000
2-------------5/13/17---------2000
2-------------5/13/17---------3000
3-------------5/14/17---------3000
3-------------5/15/17---------3000
3-------------5/16/17---------9000
```

There is a code given to me, but it's not completely working yet.

```sql
Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
            Select RT1 = sum(case when [Date] <= B2.TstDate then [Amount] else 0 end)
                  ,RT2 = sum(case when [Date] >= B2.TstDate then [Amount] else 0 end)
         From  YourTable B1
         Cross Join (Select TstDate=A.[Date]) B2
         Where [Date] between DateAdd(DAY,-2,A.[Date]) and DateAdd(DAY,2,A.[Date])
           and Year([Date])=Year(TstDate)
           and Month([Date])=Month(TstDate)
     ) B
 Where RT1>=10000 or RT2>=10000
```

Comment: Is your result correct? AccountNo 1: 1 till 4 is 4 days... Account 2: 7 till 13 is 6 days

Comment: I would say that the only eligible account is account 3

Comment: Do you mean the account has received a *SUM* of 10000 and *one* payment within 3 days? Or one 10000 payment within 3 days? Or a sum of 10000 within 3 days?

Comment: @SynerCoder Yes my result is correct, it's okay even if it's not consecutive days, as long as it is 3 days.

Comment: @JacobH Sum of 10000 within 3 days, like for example: (May 1,2,3)(May 2,3,4)(May 3,4,5) etc... every 3 days it check if the total amount is 10000

Comment: Then why is 2 in your result... The top 3 of account 2 is: 3000 + 3000 + 2000 = 8000....

Comment: Because 2 transactions are on the same day.... check...

Comment: @Hansmagz updated my answer to include also account 2. So now it works for transactions on the same day.

Comment: @Hansmagz updated my answer, now my query shows the results you wished.

Comment: within 3 days seems to have changed meaning. For me it means within a time period of 3 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common table expression: `TransInfo`

- `TransInfo` is a table with account, year, month, day, amount

The main query:

- The `[Tmiddle]` query adds a row_number based on amount per day per month per accountno
- The `[Tmiddle]` is joined again with TransInfo to limit the results to top 3 of a month AS `[Touter]` where the top 3 is >= 10.000
- The outer most query combines the result with a table again to gain the complete transaction information again

In short:

1. Filter data on top 3 amounts per day per month per year per account
2. Check if sum of amount >= 10.000
3. Show results

Query:

```sql
WITH [TransInfo] ([AccountNo], [Year], [Month], [Day], [Amount], [Rownumber])
AS
(
    SELECT [AccountNo]
          ,[Year]
          ,[Month]
          ,[Day]
          ,[Amount]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (
              PARTITION BY [AccountNo], 
              [Year],
              [Month] 
              ORDER BY [Amount] DESC
          ) AS [Rownumber]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [AccountNo]
                ,DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]) AS [Year]
                ,DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]) AS [Month]
                ,DATEPART(DAY, [Date]) AS [Day]
                ,SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount]
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Data]
        GROUP BY [AccountNo], 
                    DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]), 
                    DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]),
                    DATEPART(DAY, [Date])
    ) AS [Tinner]
)
SELECT [Data].[AccountNo]
      ,[Data].[Date]
      ,[Data].[Amount]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Data]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [TransInfo].[AccountNo]
          ,[TransInfo].[Year]
          ,[TransInfo].[Month]
          ,[TransInfo].[Day]
          ,[TransInfo].[Amount]
    FROM [TransInfo]
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [AccountNo]
              ,[Year]
              ,[Month]
        FROM [TransInfo] 
        WHERE [TransInfo].[Rownumber] <= 3
        GROUP BY [TransInfo].[AccountNo], 
                 [TransInfo].[Year],
                 [TransInfo].[Month]
        HAVING SUM ([TransInfo].[Amount]) >= 10000
    ) AS [Tmiddle]
    ON [Tmiddle].[AccountNo] = [TransInfo].[AccountNo]
    AND [Tmiddle].[Year] = [TransInfo].[Year]
    AND [Tmiddle].[Month] = [TransInfo].[Month]
    WHERE [TransInfo].[Rownumber] <= 3
) AS [Touter]
ON [Data].[AccountNo] = [TOuter].[AccountNo]
AND DATEPART(YEAR, [Data].[Date]) = [TOuter].[Year]
AND DATEPART(MONTH, [Data].[Date]) = [TOuter].[Month]
AND DATEPART(DAY, [Data].[Date]) = [TOuter].[Day]
```

---

Result: Left is query result, right is complete table

[image: Query result]

Comment: What will i put in "[Test].[dbo].[Data]" if my table name is tblTran

Comment: @Hansmagz then put there `[tblTran]` or just `tblTran`

Comment: @Hansmagz I named my database `Test`, default schema is `dbo` and table name `Data`. I use as a convention `[` and `]` around tables/databases. I find that more readable. It is also the way Microsoft SQL Server manager starts a new query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work as expected? *You may need to change the `2`'s to `3`'s depending on what you mean by 'within 3 days'.*

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT C.*
FROM YourTable C
INNER JOIN (
SELECT a.AccountNo, a.Date
FROM YourTable a
INNER JOIN YourTable b
ON a.AccountNo = b.AccountNo
AND DATEADD(DAY, 2, a.Date) <= b.Date AND b.Date >= a.Date
GROUP BY a.AccountNo, a.Date 
HAVING SUM(b.Amount) > 10000
) d
ON C.AccountNo = d.AccountNo
AND DATEADD(DAY, 2, D.Date) <= C.Date AND C.Date >= D.Date
```

Comment: this does not compile

Comment: I got error
    'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.'

Comment: Even if you correct this, it will still return nothing

Comment: Any ideas why that might be @t-clausen.dk ?